# Get Correct Date In Milliseconds From Javascript To C#

Tags: javascript, c#, momentjs

I'm using moment to convert a date string to a date object then get the milliseconds of that date and pass it to the server as a query string
the problems is that the milliseconds I get from the javascript when I try to convert it to DateTime in C# it always gives me different date

javascript

```
function RedirectToOptions() {
    var iBranchId = $('#ddl_Branches').val();
    var strDate = $('#txt_datepicker').val();
    var dtDate = moment(strDate);
    var iDate = dtDate.toDate().getTime();
    var capitalActionUrl = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Revenue", new {BranchId = "_id_", DateTimeStamp = "_date_" }))';
    var branchCapitalUrl = capitalActionUrl.replace("_id_", iBranchId);
    var branchCapitalUrl = branchCapitalUrl.replace("_date_", iDate);
    window.location.replace(branchCapitalUrl);
}
```

C#

```
public ActionResult Revenue(int? BranchId, double? DateTimeStamp)
{
    DateTime? date = (DateTimeStamp.HasValue) ? (DateTime?)DateTimeConverter.FromUnixToDateTime(DateTimeStamp.Value) : null;
    IEnumerable<RevenueDTO> revenueDTO = _Client.GetRevenue(BranchId, date);
    IEnumerable<RevenueViewModel> revenue = ViewModelConverter.RevenueDTOToRevenueViewModel(revenueDTO);

    List<BranchDTO> branchesDTO = _Client.GetAllBranches().ToList();
    var branches = ViewModelConverter.BranchDTOToBranchesViewModelList(branchesDTO);
    ViewBag.Branches = branches;

    return View(revenue);
}
```

Converting to date time

```
public static DateTime FromUnixToDateTime(double UnixTimeStamp)
{
    DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    dateTime = dateTime.AddMilliseconds(UnixTimeStamp);
    return dateTime;
}
```

when I try to pass 1/5/2016 (dd/MM/yyyy formatted) when I convert it, it becomes 1/4/2016 for some reason

Comment: For one thing, `typeof iDate == 'Nan'` will always be `false`. `typeof NaN` is `"number"`. What you're looking for there is `iDate = isNaN(iDate) ? null : iDate;`

Comment: *"when I try to pass 1/5/2016 (dd/MM/yyyy formatted) when I convert it, it becomes 1/4/2016 for some reason"* How are you checking that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to pass the date object to C# and that is using ordinary ISO 8601 standard format (e.g. 2016-01-01T12:00:00.568Z). If you call toJSON() on your date, the binder in C# should automatically convert it to C# datetime with appropriate time zone.

You will be able to see if you have a timzeone mismatch with you milliseconds in javascript easier as well than dealing with raw millisecond number.

You can read more on it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the epoch, then make sure all your timezones are set in UTC (and convert to local afterwards)... in Javascript:

```
// ...
var dtDate = moment.utc(strDate);
// ...
```

And in C#:

```
// ...
DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
// ...
```

Comment: On the JavaScript side, it's completely irrelevant and in fact `moment.utc(...)` may be harmful. The number you get from `Date#getTime` is the number of milliseconds from Jan 1 1970 at midnight **UTC**, always. Using `moment.utc(...)` will probably end up giving the wrong date as I assume the user wants to parse in local time.. The C# side of things, however, is likely useful. I don't think it's the OP's problem, but turning a milliseconds-since-The-Epoch into a `DateTime`, they definitely want to start with a UTC `DateTime`, good catch.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, but he's converting from a string, which is probably in localtime, and not specifying whether it is or not... in my browser (UTC+2 local), `moment("2016-05-01").toDate().getTime()` gives `1462053600000`, while `moment.utc("2016-05-01").toDate().getTime()` gives `1462060800000`... enough difference to go back one day (a couple hours, but since epoch is at midnight, it goes to the day before) when converting back in C#

Comment: The OP would have to tell us whether they want to parse it local; I'm pretty sure they do. But note that the OP's difference isn't one day, it's one **month**.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wow, you are right, I misread that. I'd bet that he really meant 30-4, not 1-4 then, but OP will have to clarify, yes

Comment: I think he/she's just misreading the month value somewhere, 0-based vs. 1-based.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, or it's not getting the correct format (which is a thing in `moment.js` if you don't specify the format, since browser support is inconsistent, they even note it in the docs)... I'll wait for clarification and either delete or fix the answer, but you are indeed right, I misread it totally